# What happens when bluetooth headphones run out of battery while playing music?

Tags: bluetooth, 3.0-honeycomb

I have a Motorola Xoom 3G with Android 3.0 and use it with a bluetooth headset. I'd like to know what happens when the headphones run out of battery? Does the music just stop in the same way it does when I unplug wired headphones?

Comment: Do you mean run out of battery on the Xoom or the headset?

Answer (score 3):

I go running with my Motorola Droid and a bluetooth set of headphones (Motorola ROKR S9-HD).  When the headphones die, my phone will stop playing the music.  So it basically acts the same way as removal of normal headphones.

Do note, that this does depend on the app's behavior as the developer has to actually code in the listener for headphone removal. I know this because I have had to do it myself when writing a music app ([radio reddit](http://code.google.com/p/radioreddit-android/)). But most music apps I've seen have implemented this behavior in their apps.

Comment: Do you know if google music app has this behavior implemented?

Comment: @Luiz As far as I know, it should.  Is it not doing it for you?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Xoom should stop transmitting as soon as the Headset disconnects. (Although it may start playing out of it's own speaker).

( And in this case it would disconnect as it had ran out of battery and turned off! )